# Does anyone know why my else if statements are not working?

Tags: java, if-statement

This code sorts three numbers from smallest to greatest.
However, my else statements gave me 4 errors, on lines 15, 18, 23, 26, and 31. Does anyone know why this is the case?

```
import java.util.*;
public class sortnumber {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int num1, num2, num3, random;
    num1 = scan.nextInt();
    num2 = scan.nextInt();
    num3 = scan.nextInt();
    random = 0;
    if (num1 < num2 && num1 < num3) 
        System.out.print (num1);
        if (num2 < num3)
            System.out.print (num2);
            System.out.print (num3);
        else
            System.out.print (num3);
            System.out.print (num2);            
    else if (num2 < num1 && num2 < num3)
        System.out.print (num2);
        if (num1 < num3)
            System.out.print (num1);
            System.out.print (num3);
        else
            System.out.print (num3);
            System.out.print (num1);
    else if (num3 < num2 && num3 < num1)
        System.out.print (num3);
        if (num2 < num1)
            System.out.print (num2);
            System.out.print (num1);
        else
            System.out.print (num1);
            System.out.print (num2);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to use curly braces here...

Comment: Also, as per your conditions, you can use a while loop.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't have curly braces, your indentations are wrong. What you actually coded is this:

```java
random = 0;
if (num1 < num2 && num1 < num3) 
    System.out.print (num1);
if (num2 < num3)
    System.out.print (num2);
System.out.print (num3);
else                                 // <===== ERROR
    System.out.print (num3);
System.out.print (num2);
else if (num2 < num1 && num2 < num3) // <===== ERROR
    System.out.print (num2);
if (num1 < num3)
    System.out.print (num1);
System.out.print (num3);
else                                 // <===== ERROR
    System.out.print (num3);
System.out.print (num1);
else if (num3 < num2 && num3 < num1) // <===== ERROR
    System.out.print (num3);
if (num2 < num1)
    System.out.print (num2);
System.out.print (num1);
else                                 // <===== ERROR
    System.out.print (num1);
System.out.print (num2);
```

If you add the braces indicated by your indentations, you get this:

```java
random = 0;
if (num1 < num2 && num1 < num3) {
    System.out.print(num1);
    if (num2 < num3) {
        System.out.print(num2);
        System.out.print(num3);
    } else {
        System.out.print(num3);
        System.out.print(num2);
    }
} else if (num2 < num1 && num2 < num3) {
    System.out.print(num2);
    if (num1 < num3) {
        System.out.print(num1);
        System.out.print(num3);
    } else {
        System.out.print(num3);
        System.out.print(num1);
    }
} else if (num3 < num2 && num3 < num1) {
    System.out.print(num3);
    if (num2 < num1) {
        System.out.print(num2);
        System.out.print(num1);
    } else {
        System.out.print(num1);
        System.out.print(num2);
    }
}
```

In order to prevent mistakes like that, it is commonly recommended to always use curly braces.

Comment: TYSM dude! I appreciate ur help

Answer (score 1):

An if/else if/else statement requires curly braces ({, }) if the block of code under it is more than one line. For example, your first if statement is completely valid. However, errors lie within the rest of the code. I would suggest using curly braces almost always though, as it typically makes your code more readable (even if there is only one line under the if statement).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing curly braces.

Java code does not pay attention to where new lines start or how much indentation there is. Instead, end-of-line characters (semi-colons) and curly braces are used.

While braceless if/else statements are supported in Java, they only associate one statement with the `if` or the `else`. It is considered best practice to always include the curly braces around the code you wish to include in your conditional statement.

For example, taking your first nested `if` statement:

```java
if (num1 < num2 && num1 < num3) {
    System.out.print (num1);
    if (num2 < num3) {
        System.out.print (num2);
        System.out.print (num3);
    }
    else {
        System.out.print (num3);
        System.out.print (num2);            
    }
}
```

Take a look at this page for some old but useful pointers: http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-java/flow/if/30if-braces.html